# Unable to access localhost using android mobile

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache

Hello I have a problem in accessing the localhost in my android device. I can't open my localhost in my browser. I installed an application that supports httpd, php and mysql. But when I have a connection in the Internet there's no error in displaying the localhost. But if I disable it, I can't open the localhost. Is there a configuration file that I need to configure in my device? I am using ICS. I am using 127.0.0.1 as my localhost I also did 127.0.0.1:8080 but it doesn't work also.

Comment: localhost is, in fact, local.  So using that address, you'll only be able to access it from that machine/device.  In other words, if you have a AMP stack running on your computer, you won't be able to access it from your android phone (or any device for that matter) using 127.0.0.1/localhost.  You *may* be able to access it using the LAN IP if your computer, but that's configuration dependent.

Comment: In real devices you must use 192.168.1.X (use `ifconfig` or similars to get your ip) instead of 10.0.2.2

Comment: @Jerielle if you still have this issue reply here i have solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to access your web server over your local network, then you'll need to **bind the web server to an IP address that the device can access** - this is not 127.0.0.1. Assuming you're on wifi with your android, you'll want to have your web server listen to something along the lines of 192.168.1.X. If you use 0.0.0.0 it will accept on all interfaces, this should work as well. Either case, you'll need to access your web server from your device using your web server's local IP address, not localhost and not 127.0.0.1

Comment: Hmm.. how can i view my phones ip address?

Answer (score 1):

Localhost as the url in a browser should access the server running on that device.it sounds to me maybe you are connected to a remote desktop or something. Tcp/ip utilities in particular try tracert localhoast or route. config /release maybe your touting tables are messed up,weird

Comment: How can i configure the routing table?

Comment: The routing table well some networks use static IP address where the client just sets their own IP but if someone comes along and tries to be the same IP you have a conflict. Most networks are DHCP. What is confusing me is you are saying you are hosting a web server on your droid? http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110613211815AA9lflX

Comment: http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-flush-dns.html sorry running out of space here is another link DNS server matches domain names (ie yahoo.com) to IP address. I don't think the links work for droid but at least you have some info http://rudd-o.com/archives/wifi-dhcp-network-not-working-with-your-android-phone another link

Answer (score 1):

The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case the emulator.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address `10.0.2.2` instead `127.0.0.1`. You can read more from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while working with my localhost too. The problem turns out to be with the antivirus that i was using. I was able to access my locahost again after turning the antivirus off. But because i cannot continue using my machine without an antivirus I just have to change the antivirus to another one. It worked for me, Hope it will for you too.